# write a mips code for finding and replacing a word in a sentence in MIPS architecture

Tags: mips

Develop a project that will search a word within the paragraph, and can perform the two different operations. One is to find the word present or not. Other one is to replace with another word of same size using MIPS.

Comment: Sounds like you expect this site to work as code writing service. Well, don't.

Answer (score 0):

got a program to find length of word see if it helps:
.data

string:
        .asciiz "In a distant galaxy eons before the creation of the
        mythical planet known as earth, vast civilizations have eveolved and
        ruling the galaxy is an interstellar Empire created from the ruins of an
        Old Republic that held sway for generations"
return:
        .asciiz "\n"
wordcntmsg:
        .asciiz "the word count of the length x \n"
newline:
        .asciiz "\n"
wordlength:
        .ascii  " character word = "

```
    .align 4
```

TABLE:  .space 100

```
    .text
    .globl main
```

main:

```
    la $t0, string                  # stores the address for string in $t0
    la $s1, TABLE
    addi $t2, $0, 32                # stores the ascii value for space in $t2
```

LOOP:
         lbu $t1, 0($t0)                       # load the next charater 
         beq $t1, $0, DONE               # END of STRING
         nop
         beq $t1,$t2,RESETWLC            # space
         nop
         addi $s0,$s0,1                  #inclement word length cnt.
         addi $t0,$t0,1                  #point next character.
         j LOOP
         nop

RESETWLC:
         #inclement the word lenght cnt of that word length
         # from the memory location.($s1)
         # find memory location.

```
     beq $s0,$0,PreviousSF
     nop 
     # address computation
     add $t3,$0,$s0  # 
     addi $t3,$t3,-1
     sll $t3,$t3,2   # multiply 4 to get byte address.
     add $t3,$t3,$s1 # get momory address.

     lw  $t4,0($t3)  # get previous word length cnt from the memory.
     addi $t4,$t4,1
     sw  $t4,0($t3)  # inclement and store the cnt back.
     add  $s0,$0,$0  #reset word length cnt
```

PreviousSF:
         addi $t0,$t0,1  #point next character.

```
     j LOOP
     nop
```

DONE:   # print and Exit..

```
     beq $s0,$0,PRINT
     nop 
     # address computation
     add $t3,$0,$s0  # 
     addi $t3,$t3,-1
     sll $t3,$t3,2   # multiply 4 to get byte address.
     add $t3,$t3,$s1 # get momory address.

     lw  $t4,0($t3)  # get previous word length cnt from the memory.
     addi $t4,$t4,1
     sw  $t4,0($t3)  # inclement and store the cnt back.
```

PRINT:
         la $a0, wordcntmsg
         li $v0, 4
         syscall
         li $t0,26
         li $t1,1

P_LOOP:  move $a0,$t1
         li $v0,1
         syscall
         la $a0,wordlength
         li $v0,4
         syscall
         add $t3,$0,$t1  # 
         addi $t3,$t3,-1
         sll $t3,$t3,2   # multiply 4 to get byte address.
         add $t3,$t3,$s1 # get momory address.
         lw  $a0,0($t3)  # get previous word length cnt from the memory.
         li $v0,1
         syscall
         la $a0,newline
         li $v0,4
         syscall
         addi $t1,$t1,1
         beq $t1,$t0,EXIT
         nop
         j P_LOOP
         nop

EXIT:   addi $v0, $0, 10
        syscall                         # Exits program

```
    LB_SUB:                                 #
    add $t4, $0, $a0                #
    srl $t4, $t4, 2                 #
    sll $t4, $t4, 2                 #
    sub $t5, $a0, $t4               #
    addi $t7, $0, 8                 #
    mul $t6, $t5, $t7               #
    lw $v0, 0($t4)                  #
    addi $t8, $0, 24                #
    sub $t8, $t8, $t6               #
    sll $v0, $v0, $t8               #
    srl $v0, $v0, 24                #

    jr $ra                          #
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
    para:       .space 1000                     # Pre allocate space for the input paragraph
    copypara:   .space 1000                         #copy the original paragraph
    input:      .space 30                       # Pre allocate space for the input word
    copy:       .space 30                       # Duplicate string to store the word
    replace:    .space 30                       # The alternative word
    replacemsg: .asciiz "Enter the word you want to replace with the word you want to find: \n" #display the msg to enter the alternative word
    ask:        .asciiz "Enter the paragraph:\n"            # Display msg to enter the paragraph
    askwd:      .asciiz "Enter the word you want to find:\n"    # Display msg to enter the word you want to find
    nomatch:    .asciiz "Sorry...The word is not present in the given paragraph.\n"
    match:      .asciiz "Number of times the word present in the paragraph is :-\n"
    line:       .asciiz "\n"
    origpar:    .asciiz "\nTHE ORIGINAL PARAGRAPH IS:- \n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
    result:     .asciiz "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTHE MODIFIED PARAGRAPH IS:-\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
    error:      .asciiz "Sorry...The word you you want to replace with is not the same size of the word you want to find.\n"
#======================================================================================================================================================================



#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# USE OF REGISTERS:
# 
# $s5- Stores characters of copypara
# $t5- Stores ascii value of new line
# $s2- Stores characters of word to find
# $s4- Stores characters of word to replace
# $s0- Stores characters of copy,.i.e , the extracted word
# $s1- Stores characters of the entered paragraph
# $t4- Counts the number of characters in the word to find and also acts as a counter
# $t7- Stores the number of times the find word is found
# $t6- Counts the number of characters in the extracted word
# $t0- Stores the characters of the input paragraph and is also used in the case comparision
# $t8- Stores the characters of the input paragraph
# $t2- Stores the characters of the word to find and the extracted word
# $t3- Stores the characters of the extracted word and also used in case comparision
# $s7- Stores the numer of characters of the word to find and the extracted word that are equal
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------






.text
main:

# print the msg to enter the paragraph
    li $v0,4    
    la $a0,ask
    syscall



# Take the input paragraph
    la $a0,para
    li $a1,1000                 # allocate 1000 empty space
    li $v0,8
    syscall

la $s5,copypara                 #load the the base address of the copypara




# print the msg to enter the word you want to find
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,askwd
    syscall



# take the word
    la $a0,input
    li $a2,30                   # create 30 empty spaces
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    move $s2,$a0                # move the adress of the input word from $a0 to $s2



# print the msg to enter the word you want to replace
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,replacemsg
    syscall



# take the word
    la $a0,replace
    li $a2,30
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    move $s4,$a0                # the alternative word address is on $s4




# Assign the recquired ascii values in registers and load the  base address of the recquired variables in their respective registers
    li $t5,10               # ascii value of new line
    la $s0,copy             # loading the addresses of copy of extracted word and the original para
    la $s1,para             # loading the address of the paragraph
    li $t4,1                # count the number of letters present in input word
    li $t7,0                # count the number of times the word present



# Count the number of letters prsent in the input word
    lb $t6,0($s2)               
    count:
        beq $t6,10,countreplace
        addiu $s2,$s2,1
        lb $t6,0($s2)
        addi $t4,$t4,1
    j count



# This block count the number of letters present in replace word
    countreplace :
        la $s4,replace
        li $t1,1
        lb $t3,0($s4)               
            counting:
        beq $t3,10,minor
        addiu $s4,$s4,1
        lb $t3,0($s4)
        addi $t1,$t1,1
            j counting 



# This minor restores the variable containts in their respecive registers   
    minor:
    li $t6,1                # count the number of letters present in the extracted word
    la $s2,input            # load the base address of the input word
    lb $t0,0($s1)           # loading the first character of the para

    j extract



# This block stores the the replace word in place of the input word iff the word is found
    store2:             
        la $s4,replace
        li $t0,1
    storing2:
        beq $t0,$t4,intr
            lb $t2,0($s4)
            sb $t2,0($s5)
            addiu $t0,$t0,1
            addiu $s4,$s4,1
            addiu $s5,$s5,1
    j storing2
    j intr



# This block is used to restore the original word present in the paragraph if the input word is not found
    store1:
        li $t0,1
        la $s0,copy
    storing1:
        beq $t0,$t6,intr
            lb $t2,0($s0)
            sb $t2,0($s5)
            addiu $t0,$t0,1
            addiu $s0,$s0,1
            addiu $s5,$s5,1
        j storing1



# This block is used to re-initialize the register containt after one itteration        
    intr:

        la $s4,replace
        lb $t0,0($s1)
        beq $t0,10,Display
        la $s0,copy
        li $t6,1
        addiu $s1,$s1,1
        lb $t0,0($s1)
        sb $t8,0($s5)
        addiu $s5,$s5,1


# This block is used to extract each word from the paragraph and store it in another variable called copy
    extract:
        lb $t8,0($s1)
        beq $t0,32,compare
        beq $t0,46,compare
        beq $t0,10,compare
        beq $t0,44,compare
        beq $t0,40,compare
        beq $t0,41,compare
        beq $t0,39,compare
        beq $t0,34,compare
        beq $t0,45,compare
        beq $t0,58,compare
        beq $t0,59,compare
        beq $t0,63,compare
        beq $t0,33,compare
        beq $t0,123,compare
        beq $t0,125,compare
        beq $t0,91,compare
        beq $t0,93,compare
        beq $t0,96,compare
        beq $t0,95,compare
        sb $t0,0($s0)
        addi $t6,$t6,1
        addiu $s0,$s0,1
        addiu $s1,$s1,1
        lb $t0,0($s1)
    j extract



#Compare the extracted word and the input word
    compare:
        sb $t5,0($s0)
        la $s2,input
        la $s0,copy
        lb $t2,0($s2)
        lb $t3,0($s0)
        bne $t6,$t4,store1
        li $s7,0
    check:
        bne $t2,$t3,checkagain
        backagain:
        addi $s7,$s7,1
        beq $s7,$t4,success
        addiu $s2,$s2,1
        addiu $s0,$s0,1
        lb $t2,0($s2)
        lb $t3,0($s0)

    j check


# This block is used to handle the case sensitiveness of the program
    checkagain:
        addi $t3,$t3,32
        addi $t0,$t3,-64
        beq $t2,$t3,backagain
        beq $t2,$t0,backagain
        j store1


# This block is used to count the number of times the word is present in the paragraph      
    success:

    addi $t7,$t7,1
    j store2    



# This block display the messeges according to their results
Display:
bne $t4,$t1,errormsg
beq $t7,0,msg
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,match
    syscall
    li $v0,1
    la $a0,($t7)
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,line
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,origpar
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,para
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,result
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,copypara
    syscall
    j exit


msg:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,nomatch
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,origpar
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,para
    syscall
    j exit


errormsg:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,match
    syscall
    li $v0,1
    la $a0,($t7)
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,line
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,error
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,origpar
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,para
    syscall


# The exit block
    exit:
    li $v0,10
    syscall
```